# single developer using SVN and being told need to update project

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, svn-update, svncommit

I keep a SVN repository for all my personal programming work using a hosted solution online. I am the sole user of system, it is used just a backup.

Now when I try to commit my changes I am being told the project needs to update.

From what I understand, an update is when the repository contains changes that my local copy does not have. But as the sole dev, I don't know how this is possible. There cannot be any changes on the server that I did not make.

I have tried searching around to find if updating will just resync, or potentially delete my most recent changes. I have been without internet for a week, so my local copies have many changes I do not want to lose.

This has happened many times before and always ends up with a lot of faffing around and in some cases just creating a new repository, but this seems extreme.  This time, I have about 5 projects all saying the same, so it must be something I am doing wrongly or misunderstanding.

I would like to know why this happens and the correct way to handle it.

Comment: Check out the revision you have locally in another folder from server.  Checkout current from server.  Diff.  Are you using more than one computer?  PS - an update shouldn't wipe out your local files (it should merge) but to be safe, don't update till you diff.

Comment: May it be that you committed only parts of your project, e.g. the folder "src/main/java/something/xyz" but did not update the parent folder? This leads to this effect for me sometimes.

Comment: @ebyrob I only use one machine

Comment: @DaDaDom I do not think, as I either click on the project folder and select comment, or I comment a general folder containing a few projects.

Comment: @ebyrob IT is the *shouldn't* that worries me. But thanks for the advice am checking that now. I really need to read up on this SVN marlarky, but there is always something more pressing and it never floats to the top of the todo list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes SVN just need to maintain its meta information updates, but this doesn't mean that your files will be changed or deleted.

If you are not confident about this required update, do the following:

1. Copy your local repository to another folder;
2. Perform a <kbd>SVN Update</kbd> on it and check if the files will be changed.

I see no reason to worry about, since you are "the sole developer" from your repository.

Comment: Good to know about the meta issue.

>I see no reason to worry about
The worry is / was, I lose a weeks worth of changes :)

I guess the copy folder, update, move back and commit is the best way.

Comment: Well, it's quite the same of my answer. If this is more safe for you, that's ok ;)

Comment: You appear to be spot on. I couldn't spot any changes in the files. Thanks